# adding support lib and headers to ros package

Tags: ros, package, roscpp, header

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi all,
I want to create a support class for my ros package. Let's say I want to create a class which represent a database table. This class is used by many services in my package. Where should I put the header (support.h) file and the support.cpp files? If I add them under src when I compile the class cannot be found also I tried to add under cmakelists file but without success.
Can someone help me?
Best Regads

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/10867/adding-support-lib-and-headers-to-ros-package/) by [cmsoda](https://answers.ros.org/users/430/cmsoda/) on ROS Answers with karma: 31 on 2011-08-10

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You are naming three totally different things with "putting".
A class cannot be used by a service (if you mean a ROS service), you need to provide a service server implementation.

Regarding "putting" in the sense of file location:
If other packages besides the one you are implementing are using the class it is good practice to put the header in include/mypackage/header.h, and include the file in your sources via #include "mypackage/header.h". In that case you should also take care of [exporting](http://www.ros.org/wiki/Manifest/XML#export:_.3Ccpp.3E_tag) c++ directives in the manifest.

If the header file is only used in the package you can put it in src/.

The .cpp files usually go in src/.

Regarding CMake, in most cases you don't need to put the headers in there.
If you create a new package the CMakeLists.txt already contains the commands for creating a library and exectable, you just need to uncomment them.

Can you be more precise on what exactly you are doing, give a minimal example and say what doesn't work (i.e. what means "cannot use it" for you, give the error messages)? Are you working in the same package or are you building a library package that you want to use in other packages? In the second case you need the export line in the manifest, but the term "-lros" is the linker directive for this package, i.e. instead of "-lros" it should be "-lmylib".

If class.h and class.cpp are in src/ and you have another source file in src/ you should be able to include and use class.h without a problem. If class.h is in include/mypackage/class.h, you should include that file using `#include "mypackage/class.h"`.

---

Originally posted by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) with karma: 31395 on 2011-08-10

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3